# Gremlin graph traversal that uses previous edge property to decide next edge, and the property is a Complex object

Tags: java, neo4j, gremlin

[Please look at this photo first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKWJO.jpg)

I am using gremlin to traverse the graph, first from vertex v1 to edge e1 to v2, and then from v2 to all outE(). Taking e2 as an example, I need to determine the relationship between e2's property and e1.

The specific rules are:For example, if the property of e1 is [0,1], the property array index-0 and index-1 of e2' property corresponding value cannot be both -1. So the property of e2 is [0,1], and therefore meets the requirement, and the property of e3 is [0,-1], because index-0 is 0, not -1. However, the property of e4 is [-1,-1], and the corresponding values of its index-0 and index-1 are both -1, so it does not meet the requirements. Therefore, the final path I want to get is v1-e1-v2-e2-v3 and v1-e1-v2-e3-v4.

The gremlin traversal that I want to represent looks something like this(this is my pseudocode)：

```
List<Path> paths = graphTraversalSource.V("v1")
        .outE().as("e1")
        .inV().outE().as("e2").where((e1, e2) -> {
            boolean pass = false;
            for (each property: e1.property) {
                if (e2.property[property] != -1) {
                    pass = true;
                }
            }
            return pass;
        }).path()
```

Of course, the property here should be iterated for judgment. Does gremlin support such complex property judgment？It is possible？

Comment: Gremlin currently does not support multi-properties (List or Set cardinality properties) on edges. Some implementations (e.g., TinkerGraph) will allow you to store an actual Java object (say a List [1,2]) as an edge property. Which back end database are you using? This will dictate whether what you are looking to do is possible

Comment: In general, if the list will always have just two values, the query might be a lot simpler to write if you just use two properties per edge for this. For example L1 and L2 to represent [L1,L2].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I use neo4j as the back-end database, which supports storing lists in property. The graph in the current database is just like the picture. What I'm trying to do is find some way to walk through the graph and find some paths that follow the property rules I mentioned above. Gremlin is one of my attempts. If there are others that can support this complex operation, you can also tell me. Thank you sincerely.